# Issue with Py4j tutorial

Tags: java, python, py4j

Please note I do not have any previous experience with Java. I am having issues with the following tutorial for Py4j: https://www.py4j.org/getting_started.html

I installed Py4j in an Anaconda environment. I am working in Ubuntu. I set my classpath to include the .jar file for Py4j. When I try to compile the sample code on the above web-page I received an error saying the Stack symbol didn't exist. I tried to add a line of code to import it, but that did not help either (see images).

[Error and Directory Structure (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYpXg.png)

[Source code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUg8w.png)

Stack.java

```
package py4j.examples;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Stack {
    private List<String> internalList = new LinkedList<String>();

    public void push(String element) {
        internalList.add(0, element);
    }

    public String pop() {
        return internalList.remove(0);
    }

    public List<String> getInternalList() {
        return internalList;
    }

    public void pushAll(List<String> elements) {
        for (String element : elements) {
            this.push(element);
        }
    }
}
```

StackEntryPoint.java

```
package py4j.examples;

import py4j.GatewayServer;
import py4j.examples.Stack; // <-- I added this line but it does not solve the issue

public class StackEntryPoint {

    private Stack stack;

    public StackEntryPoint() {
        stack = new Stack();
        stack.push("Initial Item");
    }

    public Stack getStack() {
        return stack;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new StackEntryPoint());
        gatewayServer.start();
        System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
    }

}
```

I haven't used Java before, so I'm confused about how to link classes during compilation. I've tried looking extensively at Java documentation/resources online and questions related, but can't seem to solve this problem. Could someone point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your source code as text!

Comment: @csabinho just added the source code as text too. Sorry about that!

Comment: you need to specify the classpath which contains your all required source files. For example `javac -cp ".:/path/to/pyjar" path/to/stackentry.java`

Comment: Yes I had already set my jar file in classpath by typing: `export Classpath=/path/to/py4j.jar` you can see the actual path in the first image I linked above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compiling class `StackEntryPoint`, but you have not compiled the `Stack` class yet. Do so first, otherwise it cannot use it to compile `StackEntryPoint`.

Normally your IDE would solve this for you, but you've got a special setup going here (with the Python integration) so I'm not sure how you'd integrate it.

Ideally, you'll build your Java library as a separate JAR using conventional Java tooling (e.g. Maven and IntelliJ IDEA), but it's not a bad exercise to learn to do it bare-bones first.

Comment: I had already tried compiling `Stack` before `StackEntryPoint` but still get the same error. I also tried compiling them both at the same time with `javac Stack.java StackEntryPoint.java` but then when I try running `StackEntryPoint.class` it says could not find or load main class.

Comment: You need to make sure that the folder where your compiled `Stack` class is, is also on your classpath. This could be as simple as appending `:.` to your classpath, if I recall correctly.